# Convert type to another type C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I want to add a component to an object with a type parameter, but it says it cannot be used like this:

```
void AddScript<T>(GameObject self)
    {
        self.AddComponent<T>();
    }
```

[image: The type 'T' cannot be used as a type parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'GamObject.AddComponant()'. There is no boxing Conversion From 'T' To UnityEngine.Componant']

I tried searching for a solution but only found ways to converting a object to another object.  I also tried boxing conversion like it said:

```
void AddScript<T>(GameObject self)
    {
        self.AddComponent<[Component]T>();
    }
```

But the compiler said that it was a type, and it was not valid.

So how do you convert a type to another type?

Comment: What is the use of `T` in this method?

Comment: Try `void AddScript<T>(GameObject self) where T : UnityEngine.Component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the same Type constraint probably.

```
void AddScript<T>(GameObject self)
  where T : UnityEngine.Component {
 // ...
}
```

The `where` above is a type constraint which means that `T` must be any type that inherits from or is a `Component`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's telling you that you have to pass a `UnityEngine.Component` type, you will most likely have to constrain your `T` to that type:

```
void AddScript<T>(GameObject self) where T : UnityEngine.Component
{
    self.AddComponent<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type argument `T` you have created is less constrained than the type argument of `self.AddComponent<T>()`.

This is how `AddComponent<T>` is implemented for Unity objects:

```
public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component
{
  return this.AddComponent(typeof (T)) as T;
}
```

So you will also need a type constraint that is either Component, or a derivative of Component.

Answer (score 1):

The AddComponent method has a generic type constrant where T must be Component.

You can change your method singature as follows

```
void AddScript<T>(GameObject self) where T : Component
{
    self.AddComponent<T>();
}
```